# How can I show circle points in a separate window using OpenCV and C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, video-streaming

If I draw some circles "in a sequence of frames" in OpenCV by using this function:

```
void circle(Mat& img, Point center, int radius, const Scalar& color,
            int thickness = 1, int lineType = 8, int shift = 0);
```

...is there any way to show these circle points in a separate window?

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many windows as you like using the `imshow` function. The first argument of imshow is the window name, the second one is the image you are going to display on it.

So, a simple way to show these circles in a separated window is to create a brand new Mat (with the desired dimensions), draw the points on it and display it using `imshow`. To draw the points you may use the circle function with `radius=1`.

More info: [docs.opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org)